# Pass data ViewController to NavigationController in Swift 3

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have a tabbar controller. This tabbar controller has 2 button. First and second. When first button clicked open a sign in form in view controller, second button for register form. If user filled correct info and tapped login button I want to send homepage. This page a navigation controller. I can do this. It is ok from here. But I want to send user email to navigation controller, i use email for user info. How can I do it?

Comment: No @dan, I can send data between two view controller. My question for one view controller to navigation controller.

Comment: A navigation controller is a view controller.

Comment: Actually you are right, but when I try to send data btwn 2 own class UIViewController evrything is ok. But first of UIviewController other NavigationController I cant. I want to sent via programaticaly not func in perform segue.